# Moq return same delegate as parameter

Tags: c#, generics, moq

I am very new to Moq and looking for a way to be able to mock up the following interface.

```
public interface ICacheProveder
{
    T GetOrAddToCache<T>(string key, Func<T> populateFunc);
}
```

This interface is currently being used to cache items such as code tables. The mock would need to return the result of anything that was passed into the via populateFunc. I am currently using Moq version 4.2.1502.911

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To return the result of the `Func` passed as argument you can make use of [`Returns` from Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#methods).

In the example below, for simplicity, I choose `T` to be a `string`, it can be changed based on your needs.

```
[Test]
public void TetMethod()
{
    //Setup
    var cacheProveder = new Mock<ICacheProveder>();

    cacheProveder.Setup(a => a.GetOrAddToCache<string>(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<Func<string>>()))
                    .Returns((string key, Func<string> populateFunc) => { return populateFunc(); });

    // rest of the code

}
```

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to use generics or will I need do run a setup method for each type I plan to mock?

Comment: @Aaron You have to run a setup method for each type you plan to mock.